# Virtualbox/VMWare on USB3 SSD?

Tags: virtualbox, ssd, virtual-machine, vmware, usb-3

I'm investigating whether we (at work) should move our virtual windows machines from our local harddrives to one external USB3 SSD.

Background:
The "problem" many of us have Macbooks and PCs with 256gb SSDs and we all are in need of running Virtual Machines with 3 different versions of Internet Explorer (9,10 and 11). This sums up to 3 virtual machines at about 20gb each for every developer. Since we all have limited disk space, using 60gb each, just for IE testing seems like a waste.

So what I would like to know is, if I could move these 3 virtual machines to a USB3 SSD drive and if they would perform acceptable to good or even great. We are open to use either VMWare or Virtualbox.

If anyone has experience with this, recommendations on what type of USB3 drives I should buy would also be very helpful.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up buying a Samsung Portable 500gb SSD T1 with USB3 and it's very fast. It's all I needed and I can recommend this solution for anyone with the same problems

Answer (score -1):

Do not forget about rotating hard drives. A right kind of it (such as WD "black" series) may be fast enough for you. Also consider a RAID configured for speed.